# Error in getting Value from Input Radio button

Tags: javascript, dom, firebase-realtime-database, null, typeerror

```js
var numb=0;
var responsen=[];
uid=123;
function submit() {
    for (var index = 0;index<numb; index++){
            var form = document.getElementById("value");
            var name=index+1;
            const query='#'+name
            var radval=document.querySelector(query).value;
            responsen.push(radval)
            console.log(name)
            console.log(responsen)
        }
    ref1=firebase.database().ref('beta/' + 'uid/'+ code1+"/"+"simplesheet/"+"0/")
    ref1.once("value", function(snapshot){
        var numb=snapshot.val().num.count;
        console.log(responsen)
    });
    document.getElementsByClassName("ht")[0].innerText="YOUR RESPONSE HAS BEEN SUBMITTED" 
    //zzzzz
    firebase.database().ref('beta/' + 'uid/'+ code1 +"/"+"simplesheet/"+"0/"+"answers/"+uid+"/").set({
    response:responsen.toString(),
    endtime:0
     })
     console.log(responsen)
}
```

```html
<form id="value" method="POST" action="submit()">this<hr><br>Que<br><input type="radio" value="1" name="1">is<br><input type="radio" value="2" name="1">a<br><input type="radio" value="3" name="1">question<br><input type="radio" value="4" name="1">papaer<br><hr> xas<hr><br>serew<br><input type="radio" value="1" name="2">werwer<br><input type="radio" value="2" name="2">werewr<br><input type="radio" value="3" name="2">werwer<br><input type="radio" value="4" name="2">werwr<br><hr></form>
```

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to upload values of selection of the radio buttons.

I have tried getting value of radio button with all the solutions provided in this question :[How to get value of selected radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839169/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)
but it shows error in all three types I have tried.
I can't figure out the problem.
I have set up this js-fiddle please see this:
[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vednig12/L34ufvcq/8/)
Reffered to this one also..>>[Using querySelector with IDs that are numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers)
[image: Error Raised]
Zomming in to It:
[image: Error Handling]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](https://img.techpowerup.org/201027/skpu2.png))</sub>
After Updating:
It still Gives Error
[image: After]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](https://img.techpowerup.org/201027/varcg.png))</sub>
[image: After Another ERROR]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](https://img.techpowerup.org/201027/w29qr.png))</sub>
EDIT:
And after reading all the suggested options I think it is least possible to do that with firebase the way I have used it using only JavaScript.
'cause they require declaring it on page load but content loads using firebase after document load.
See These answers:[a1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096639/13935716) [a2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928205/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null)[a3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers)
from what I read I think the problem is somewhere in V8's implementing ES6 
 ES6's query selector also fails...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally solved this.

```
for (var index = 0;index<numb; index++){
        var form = document.getElementById("value");
        const forms = document.forms.value;
        var name=index+1;
        const radios = forms.elements[name.toString()].checked;
        const query='['+'name="'+name+'"]'
        var radval=document.querySelector('input'+query+':checked');
        var radval1=document.querySelector('input'+query+':checked');
        //var val1=form.getElementById(name).value;
    

**if (radval1!=null) {
            responsen.push(radval.value)
        }
        else{
            responsen.push("")
        }

        console.log(radval,radios)
        console.log(responsen)
    }**
```

Another way to do this.
See this fiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/vednig12/hwbd9fq5/9/

- Problem was with null value given when object did not catered to needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the name of the elements. You are using only number. There should be at least on character on id or name field as per [HTML5 spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). Besides you are trying to use selector `#1` which is id selector. your selector for the name should be like this,

```
document.querySelector('[name="yourElemeName"]')
```

Comment: well, now i have solved the problem and i think naming it a number is well suited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use id or class name in your querySelector.
If you wish to use class it should be like document.querySelector('.classname')
And if you want to use Id then document.querySelector('#IdofElement')

Comment: Please check that the variable query value is correct. It should point to the correct element which value you required.